# ¿Cómo leo las líneas de un archivo de texto con GeneXus?

Tags: genexus, txt

Quiero programar un programa que leea archivos .txt con Genexus. El problema que no se como implementar el ReadAllLines para leer cada linea del .txt y encontrar el dato que necesito.
En cambio en Javacript si se hacerlo, puedo colocar ese código en Genexus?, yo creo que no pero tal vez si y no lo se...
Quiero hacerlo en Genexus ya que permite trabajar con Bases de Datos mucho mas fácil que con codigo 'puro'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No me queda claro el enfoque de tu pregunta.
Si se puede escribir Javascript en GeneXus utilizando el objeto UserControl.
De todas formas, entiendo que lo que realmente quieres es leer un archivo txt. Como puedes ver en este [artículo](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?24070,File%20data%20type%3A%20Text%20file%20handling) esto lo puedes hacer con el tipo de datos File.
Si te creas una variable de ese tipo vas a poder cargar el archivo con el método OpenRead(), primero declaras el origen `&File.Source = "C:\Files\Data.txt"` y luego lo abres `&File.OpenRead()`.
El método ReadAllLines() te retorna una colección de VarChar con cada línea del archivo o sino el método ReadAllText() retorna todo el texto dentro de un único VarChar.
Recuerda que al terminar de leer debes cerrar el archivo con el método `&File.Close()`

Answer (score 2):

Como bien contesta [Mr. User](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/379556/291), se puede agregar JavaScript, pero creo que ese no es el objetivo de tu pregunta (cambiaría el título).

La forma de obtener las lineas de un archivo es la siguiente:

```
&File.Source = 'Text.txt'
if &File.Exists()
    &varcharcollection = &File.ReadAllLines()
    for &fileLine in &varcharcollection
        msg(&fileLine, status)      
    endfor
else
    msg('File not found', status)
endif
```

No es necesario abrir el archivo antes (ni cerrarlo después), ya que el método `ReadAllLines` abre, lee, y cierra el archivo.

Si el archivo fuese muy grande, y prefirieras no cargarlo todo en memoria, ahí sí tienes que abrirlo antes, iterar leyendo de a una línea y cerrarlo al final:

```
&File.Source = 'Text.txt'
if &File.Exists()
    &File.OpenRead()
    do while not &File.EOF
        &fileLine = &File.ReadLine()
        msg(&fileLine, status)      
    enddo
    &File.Close()
else
    msg('File not found', status)
endif
```